# htaccess redirect / (root) only and mask URL

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, apache-2.4, web-server, .htaccess

I have a web server as a part of a company network (Apache). Our main page is only a landing page and I have an employee hub as a subfolder `example.com/hub`.

I would like to keep `/hub` website on the server, however, I would like to migrate `/` (root) website (it's going to be a new website) to another host and keep the domain as it is.

So, if someone visits our domain first it hits our server, however, is then being redirected to the other host but the domain is the same. But when visit `example.com/hub` it is loaded from the company web server.

How can I do this?

Comment: This is only possible with a reverse proxy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insist on keeping the separation via the path `/hub/` you will have to use a reverse proxy. Either you configure your local webserver to proxy everything except `/hub` to the hosted server, or you configure your hosted server to proxy `/hub` to your local server. Either way all traffic will go through one of those two servers.

If you want to separate this completely you will have to switch to a subdomain. Point `example.com` to your hosted server and `hub.example.com` to your local server. Of course you can configure the hosted server to answer all requests to `/hub` with redirects to `hub.example.com` to prevent existing URLs from breaking, but new links should use the subdomain instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for the extensive answer!